# Keyboard appears twice when UITextField becomes first responder after custom segue performed

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, segue, becomefirstresponder

So the problem is: when I push a button on a source view the custom segue performed.

**Here is the code (pretty standard):**

```
class FirstCustomSugue: UIStoryboardSegue {
override func perform() {

    let initalView = self.source.view as UIView?
    let destinationView = self.destination.view as UIView?

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width

    initalView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
    destinationView?.frame = CGRect(x: screenWidth, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

    let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    appWindow?.insertSubview(destinationView!, aboveSubview: initalView!)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
        // Left/Right
        initalView?.frame = (initalView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0))!
        destinationView?.frame = (destinationView?.frame.offsetBy(dx: -screenWidth, dy: 0))!
    }) { (Bool) in
        self.source.present(self.destination, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

I call `myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` in `viewDidiAppear` (call to super is included).

When I set a simulator's «Slow animations» On I can clearly see that keyboard first appears alongside the animation and after animation is complete it reappears.

I included the example а the segue because when I switch to the standard segues there is no such problem. If you need any other code example I will update a post.

Using custom segues because I am not using `navigationController` for views I transition between and default modal segues are not an option.

My guess is that `viewDidAppear` is called twice, because even when I set `myTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and `myTextField.isEnabled = false` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` (before or after the super in both methods) and then setting those to true in `viewDidAppear` right after call to super the result is the same.

TNX in advance!

Comment: `My guess is that viewDidAppear is called twice` did you try debugging it?

Comment: Yes. it is called twice. Simple print statements showed it clearly

Comment: Use CATransition instead of UIView animation like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12946696/4687211

Comment: Also calling twice viewWillAppear, but only once viewDidLoad

Comment: I saw that answer but I wonder is there a way to do it without the suggested solution.

Comment: You can always hack it and make some `if myTextField.isfirstresponder` or some other ugly stuff but segues should be done with `CATransition`

Comment: My guess is that `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` is called twice because at first it is called by the segue, and then by `self.source.present(...)`

Comment: If you need a custom transition (as I can tell by your segue's code) why not use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` & co?

Comment: Hi Dan. Indeed self.source.present(...) caused viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear to be called twice, but now done button on keyboard not working and not hiding keyboard in textFieldShouldReturn

Comment: @Lu_ Thank you! Switched to the CATransition and it worked out!!!

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed segue’s perform to the following:

```
    let sourceViewController = self.source
    let destinationViewController = self.destination

    let transition = CATransition()

    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

    let appWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    appWindow?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    sourceViewController.present(destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)ere
```